# Collection of subforms in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have following form in Symfony 2.8:

```
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('phone', 'text')
        ->add($this->createFormBuilder()
            ->create('address', 'form', array('virtual' => true))
            ->add('street', 'text')
            ->add('city', 'text')
            ->add('zip', 'text')
        )
        ->getForm();
```

And I would like to dynamically add addresses in JS. I can add by CollectionType single input, as per following documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

But I would like to add whole subform address. So I would like to achieve following HTML result:

```
<input name="form[address][0][street]" />
<input name="form[address][0][city]" />
<input name="form[address][0][zip]" />
```

not

```
<input name="form[address][street][0]" />
<input name="form[address][city][0]" />
<input name="form[address][zip][0]" />
```

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you maybe try creating your own FormType for Address and using that with the CollectionType?

Comment: You can use `collection` type for it. Options `allow_add` and `allow_delete` allows to add/delete subforms in collection. Collection form property `prototype` contains form that can be used as a base for creating new subforms by JS. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: hey guys, thanks for hints, so I solved it in the way, which is in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the comments I solved in in following way:

```
class Address
{
    private $street;
    private $city;

    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->street = $city;
    }
}

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('street', 'text')
            ->add('city', 'text');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Address::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

then in controller:

```
$data = array(
            "addresses" => array(
                0 => new Address())
        );

// $data is to show first empty subform

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'text')
            ->add('phone', 'text')
            ->add('addresses',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
                    'empty_data' => true
                ))
            ->getForm();
```

and the twig template looks like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}

    {{ form_label(form.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}

    {% for address in form.addresses %}
         {{ form_widget(address) }}
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```